# How can I retain lower camel case properties while using Json SerializerSettings?

Tags: c#, njsonschema

I'm trying to setup JSON validation using NJsonSchema. I want that C# class properties are translated to lower camel case when validated.

I managed to achieve that goal by passing a custom `JsonSchemaGeneratorSettings` object to `JsonSchema.FromType()`.

```cs
var schema = JsonSchema.FromType<Cat>(new JsonSchemaGeneratorSettings {
        DefaultPropertyNameHandling = PropertyNameHandling.Default
    });
var schemaData = schema.ToJson();
var errors = schema.Validate(req.ReadAsString() ?? "");
foreach (var error in errors)
    Console.WriteLine(error.Path + ": " + error.Kind);
```

However, this shows the following warning:

> CS0618: 'JsonSchemaGeneratorSettings.DefaultPropertyNameHandling' is obsolete: 'Use SerializerSettings directly instead. In NSwag.AspNetCore the property is set automatically.'

I tried to modify the code as follows, but this code defaults to creating upper camel case properties again:

```cs
JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings {
    MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Error,
    ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver() {
        NamingStrategy = new CamelCaseNamingStrategy()
    }            
};

var schema = JsonSchema.FromType<Cat>(new JsonSchemaGeneratorSettings {
        DefaultPropertyNameHandling = PropertyNameHandling.Default
    });
var schemaData = schema.ToJson();
var errors = schema.Validate(req.ReadAsString() ?? "");
foreach (var error in errors)
    Console.WriteLine(error.Path + ": " + error.Kind);
```

How can I use JsonSerializerSettings *and* retain lower camel case properties?